# Conditional field display in node template

Tags: 8, theming

I have a specific content type that I am overwriting the template node--contenttype.html.twig.

This conent type has 4 fields.

- Title
- Body
- Image
- Video

I am trying to hide the image field from displaying if VIDEO field has value. Which I am doing by using this code in custom twig template.

```
{% if node.field_video is not empty %}
{{ content.field_video }}
{% else %}
  {{ content.field_image }}
{% endif %}
```

The only problem is that I get one of the fields printed as needed plus I get both fields shown.

Video filed is displayed, plus I get an image and video shown again. Wherever those fields are positioned in MANAGE DISPLAY.

If I disable the two fields in MANAGE DISPLAY then, nothing shows up at all.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: You can’t disable the fields from display - they will not be added to the content render array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote that you are using Twig conditions to selectively print fields, but they show up twice now. This most likely is, because your template still renders the entire `content` variable somewhere like `{{ content }}`.

You can easily avoid the fields being rendered twice by using the [without](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates#without) Twig filter. Locate the `{{ content }}` part in your template and alter it to

```
{{ content|without('field_video', 'field_image') }}
```

Comment: Mario, do you have any tips on how to implement this on a display suite template? I have created a custom layout and placed it under the templates directory in my subtheme. But on the ds-custom-lyout.html.twig I only see regisons, no contect variable. {% set left = left|render %}
{% set middle = middle|render %}
{% set right = right|render %}

{% if (left and not right) or (right and not left) %}
  {% set layout_class = 'group-one-sidebar' %}
{% elseif (left and right) %}
  {% set layout_class = 'group-two-sidebars' %}
{% elseif (left) %}